# what are arguments defined in quotes

Tags: c++, string, cstring

In some function calls I see stuff like this.

```
function(variable1, "someValue");
```

I have some questions based on this

1) How does c++ treat the second argument ?

2) if some function takes a cstring then why do we get error when we do the following

```
functionTakingCString(stringVariable.c_str() + "someValue");
```

Is there some way around instead of declaring a const char variable? Please correct me if I m wrong some where.

Comment: Technically string literals are `const char (&)[N]`, not `const char *`. It does make a difference sometimes, like if `function` takes the literal by reference.

Answer (score 3):

They are called *string literals* and if you want to take an argument that is a string literal like that you normally pass a `const std::string&` or a `const char*`, depending on what your API requires.

Answer (score 2):

> 2) if some function takes a cstring then why do we get error when we do the following

That's because the '+' operator is not overloaded for `char *` type. You could concatenate it to `stringVariable` of type `string` for which the `+` operator has been overloaded to concatenate two strings, and then get the `c_str()` to pass to a function accepting `char *` or `const char *`.

Answer (score 1):

1. const char*
2. Binary operator `+` cannot be applied on `const char*` operand types. If one is a std::string, then it works because of operator overloading.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is a const char*. In some cases you may be able convert from one type to another if you have a special [converting constructor](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr384.htm) of the desired type that takes in the given type. The compiler can do this for you in some cases.

In this example string has a constructor that takes in a const char* so the compiler can turn a const char* into a string for you under the covers. If you want to stop this kind of behavior look into the explicit keyword.

The char* type isn't actually an class so it doesn't have a + operator that works for strings. However,

```
(stringVariable + "someValue").c_str()
```

will work because stringVariable is a string and it's plus operator can cooerce a char* into a string.